# Checking Logical Correctness of a TeX Document

Tags: tex-general

Is there a way to check the logical correctness of my TeX document?

Suppose in the proof of Theorem 2.1 I refer to Theorem 3.5. I would call this logical incorrectness.

This may happen when we reorganize our document. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think this has anything to do with TeX. By the way, there are hundreds of papers and books where proofs of theorems refer to other theorems that are proved later on.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it incorrect. Sometimes you mentions something that would be proved or described in detail after when it's first mentioned. To your question, no idea :) **EDIT** egreg was first by a long minute!

Comment: I see. I would really like to avoid such a thing in my notes. Let's see if someone knows something. Thanks egreg and Manuel.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a proof assistant, such as [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), in Latex ?

Comment: No. I am using TeX as plainly as possible.